# IntelliJ version control shows a file has changed without having any changes

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I wrote a Java tool which assists me with coding at my work: It applies "code hacks" to a specific java file. When I "activate" such a "code hack", the java code of that specific java file is altered. When I "deactivate" that "code hack", the applied code hack is removed from the java file and there should be no more changes to that java file, but my IntelliJ still highlights it blue and shows it in the "Version Control / Local Changes"-Tab:

[image]

When I show the "Difference"-window for that file, the following message is shown:

[image]

My first thought was that my "Code hack"-tool writes the content of the file using a wrong charset, but I tried all the standard charsets and none of them seemed to work.
How can I get this working, so the java file is unchanged after the "code hack" is "deactivated"?

Comment: It's probably due to line ending differences. What does `git status` on the command line show?

Comment: It may be chmod difference (executable flag) also

Comment: `git status` output:
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in at/pkp/ra/rainterface/RAInterface.java.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.

You are right, I used only `\n` as line endings, using `\r\n` fixed the problem. Thanks! :)